# Nattable: Search and Replace functionality

Tags: java, search, replace, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I'm trying to implement Search and Replace on Nattable. How can it be done? Is there any existing API or solution for the same?

Comment: @SiddhartKoul were you able to implement search/replace? I'm about to do it so interested in ideas.

Comment: @fredrik Yes I was able to implement replace. You can do a Regex replace in the table for all the cells with the matching string.
Check this out for replace https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NatTable has a search function already included. The according search dialog can be opened via CTRL + F. It has no replace function included. But replacing actually means to change/edit/update cell content.